# How to print only the first non-blank line using sed

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, text-parsing

Given the following file, where line 1 is blank:

```
\n
Line 2\n
Line 3\n
```

How would you output only "Line 2" using sed?

Solutions using other standard UNIX tools, for example awk, are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples work if you have an empty line, but not if you have a line containing characters like space or tab.

I think this version would work even if the "blank" line contains spaces or tabs.

> sed '/[^[:blank:]]/q;d' file

Answer (score 11):

Using a version of grep with the `-m` switch, such as [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/General-Output-Control.html#General-Output-Control) or [OpenBSD](https://man.openbsd.org/grep.1#m) grep:

```
grep -m 1 . file
```

This stops reading the file after 1 matching line. `.` matches any character, so the first non-empty line will match.

Using any version of awk (essentially the same as the sed version):

```
awk '/./{print;exit}' file
```

Comment: `awk 'NF{print;exit}'` would also work depending on whether they count whitespace as blank or not.

Comment: The non-standard `-m` extension was added to OpenBSD's grep(1) on Dec 9, 2017. Nice. Even more simple than sed.

Answer (score 4):

### Multi-line version with comments

```
sed -n '  # use -n option to suppress line echoing
  /./ {   # match non-blank lines and perform the enclosed functions
          # print the non-blank line, i.e., "Line 2"
          p
          # quit right after printing the first non-blank line
          q
      }
' file
```

### Single-line version without comments

```
sed -n '/./{p;q;}' file
```

Comment: I would probably have said `sed '/./q;d' file`, but either works.

Comment: @Wintermute, very nice. I did not realize the line would be echoed before quitting.

Comment: It will if the `-n` option is not given to sed. `q` is similar to `n` in this regard. This behavior can be used nicely in this case, but to be honest, it is vexing more often than not. GNU sed has a `Q` command that quits without printing regardless of `-n` because of this.